# Loading different files into 1 df from gcs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-storage

This the code segment I am having an issue with, I want the **wtc** and **neaq** files to load together to Bigquery. But it is being loaded in separately and overwriting each other in BQ. The structure of the 2 files are exactly the same as each other. I think it has to do with the same the logic is set up, but I can't figure it out.

```
elif cur_pub[1].lower() == 'tremor':
            tremorfiles = list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))  # blob
            dfm = pd.DataFrame()
            for file in tremorfiles:
                if 'gor' in file.name:
                    filename = list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file.name))  # blob
                    #dfm = pd.DataFrame()
                    for file_name in filename:
                        if '.csv' in str(file_name.name):
                            rdf = self.LoadCSV(file_name, sep, rowstoskip)
                            if not rdf.empty:
                                rdf.insert(0, "filename", str(file_name.name).replace(' ', ''))
                                dfm = pd.concat([dfm, rdf], ignore_index=True)
                    if not dfm.empty:
                        clean_data = cln.general_clean_data(dfm, cur_pub[1].lower(), file_name.name)
                        table_prefix = str('tremor_gor_')
                        table_id = config.clouddb.bq_project() + '.' + bucket_name_ + '.' + table_prefix + current_day
                        bq.load_tremor_gor_to_bq(table_id, clean_data)  # load clean data into BQ
                else:
                    sub_list = ['wtc', 'neaq']
                    tremorlist = list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))
                    for sub_file in sub_list:
                        filelist = list([file.name for file in tremorlist if sub_file in file.name])  # file list
                        dfm = pd.DataFrame()
                        for num, name in enumerate(filelist):  # , start=0
                            filename = list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=filelist[num]))  # blob
                            for file_name in filename:  # loop through each subset of files from the pattern
                                if '.csv' in str(file_name.name):
                                    if 'wtc' in str(file_name.name):
                                        rdf = self.LoadCSV(file_name, sep, rowstoskip)
                                        rdf = rdf.assign(audience='-')
                                    else:
                                        rdf = self.LoadCSV(file_name, sep, rowstoskip)
                                    if not rdf.empty:
                                        rdf.insert(0, "filename", str(file_name.name).replace(' ', ''))
                                        #print(rdf.to_string())
                                        dfm = pd.concat([dfm, rdf], ignore_index=True)

                    if len(filename) == 1 or num == len(filename):  # only execute below when all files in sublist have been read
                        if not dfm.empty:
                            print(dfm.to_string())
                            clean_data = cln.general_clean_data(dfm, cur_pub[1].lower(), file_name.name)
                            table_prefix = str('tremor_')
                            table_id = config.clouddb.bq_project() + '.' + bucket_name_ + '.' + table_prefix + current_day
                            bq.load_tremor_to_bq(table_id, clean_data)  # load clean data into BQ
```

This is the outcome out the load, it is not loading the **wtc** file:
tremor
Loaded 1158 rows and 12 columns to analyticsdata-293414.emaildownloads.tremor_gor_20230428

Loaded 110 rows and 14 columns to analyticsdata-293414.emaildownloads.tremor_20230428

Loaded 110 rows and 14 columns to analyticsdata-293414.emaildownloads.tremor_20230428